# count down on button press in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

In game when I press a button on my keyboard it will start a countdown on a timer  until it hits zero. Is this something that is possible to make in blender game engine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, easily through logic bricks and using a text object.

In this example, the property `start` rules if the countdown is started. When Spacebar is pressed `start` becomes `True`, then the `Text` property gets decreased each 60 frames (that is, 1 second).

Example blend file provided below.

[image]

Example file: [image]